# UiSelector descriptionContains does not work

Tags: android-testing, android-uiautomator

I am trying to write simile UiAutomator test.

When I inspect screen either throung layout inspector or UiAutomator. I see edit text with content description that says "Work Email"

However I am trying to locate the same element

```
 val workEmailTextField = device.findObject(
            UiSelector().descriptionContains("Work Email")
        )
  if (workEmailTextField.waitForExists(TIMEOUT)) {
      Log.d("TEST,"Pass")
  } else {
      Log.d("TEST,"Fail")
  }
```

It always displays "Fail" on some emulators, but works great on other.

Why the differences across emulators when running simple UiAutomator test. Is there some setup I need to do for UiAutomator to works?

Comment: Any luck finding a solution to that?

Comment: No luck. UiAutomator tests remain flaky for me.